# How to "Bind" a number to a string of words/phrase so that I can call it up in a loop?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project where I need to have the computer print the 12 days of Christmas lyrics. I thought of an idea where I make a FOR loop and have it repeat 12 times. Every time the day changes with the unary operator "++" Here's what I mean:

```
int main()
{

    string Print = first = 1; //Here I want first to become a number so that I can call it up in FOR loop.

    cout << "On the first day of Christmas, \nmy true love sent to me\nA partridge in a pear tree.\n" << endl;


    for(int loop = 0; loop <= 12; loop++)//This part is a simple for loop, it starts at 0 and goes to 12 until it stops.
    {
    cout << "On the " << (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...12) << " day of Christmas,\nmy true love sent to me\n" << endl;  HERE!!!!
```

Here is where I'm having issue. I want the numbers to call in strings to say the day. As in x = 1 will call in "First" and then I can move the number up by using "x++" which will result in x = 2 and then it will say "Second".. all the way to 12. Anyone know how I can resolve this issue? 
        }

Comment: have you considered using [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: use an array or vector with string contents - that's what they're for, after all!

Comment: No I haven't (yet, but soon!), I'm not sure how to use those since I'm still fairly new to C++ but I'll be sure to go look it up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: As a newbie, I suggest you start by using a simple array. This website should help: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/61-arrays-part-i/

Comment: @Conduit Why use naked arrays when [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) are more effective solutions?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious diving into the STL early hinders understanding of how the STL works, IMO. I started with naked arrays, and am much better for it.

Comment: I've read a bit on the website (It's very helpful!) I was wondering.. Can I use the unary operator "++" on (anArray[0] = 2;) for example to make it anArray[1] which has a different value?

Comment: Arrays are very fickle - they don't like to change the number of items they contain. I suggest you read ALL of that website. It's where I learned to code in C++, and it is a fantastic starting point.

Comment: Alright, will do! Thanks

Comment: No trouble. I'd stick to this website, too - make sure you follow the rules in the help center, and it will be a great resource for you while you're learning: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

This involves a simple but important part of programming called an array. I don't want to give you the answer directly - you need to use these (or similar structures) **all the time**, and it is very important to practice their use and understand them. Let's make a simple program using arrays that prints "Hello World":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string words[2];   //make an array to hold our words
    words[0] = "Hello";     //set the first word (at index 0)
    words[1] = "World";     //set the second word (at index 1)
    int numWords = 2;       //make sure we know the number of words!

    //print each word on a new line using a loop
    for(int i = 0; i < numWords; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << words[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should be able to figure out how to use a similar tactic to get the functionality you asked for above. [Working Ideone here](http://ideone.com/XtnQ4c).

Comment: Yes! That's a program that was similar to what I was thinking.